# Oneplus 6T stuck on bootloader after rooting

Tags: rooting, boot-loop, oneplus6t

I tried to root my Oneplus 6T. Now the phone is stuck on the bootloader

[image]

If I continue with `START`, the device is going to a loop, never completing the boot process.

I tried booting the boot image with fastboot like `fastboot flash boot twrp-3.2.3-1-fajita.img`, but after that, an error message is displayed

[image]

> ```
> QUALCOMM CrashDump Mode  
> -------------------------
>
> Attempted to kill init!  exitcode=0x0000000b
> ```

After searching, I found that the MSM tool can flash the device with a fresh install, but the software is not available on macOS.

Is there any alternative for the MSM tool? How can I get at least go back to a non-rooted state?

Comment: I don't know the resolution, but you can install VirtualBox or a VM and install Windows on it. plug in the Android/ install the software in the VM; it should work if it needs windows.

Answer (score 0):

After an extensive Google search and reading xda forum, I realized that the official TWRP image does not support the latest OxygenOS - `11.1.2.2`.

Fortunately, there is an unofficial patch that works on OOS 11.1.2.2. I got it from [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/OnePlus6t/comments/urj9bw/trying_to_install_twrp_on_oos_11122_and_getting/). After flashing the newly downloaded image, I could boot to TWRP recovery.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Consider [edit]ing to summarize the content and/or expand the answer!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).